# Rails state_machine - conditional validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, state

When using state_machine, how can you conditionally validate fields in the below way?

```
state :unlit do      
end

state :fire do
  if is_big_fire?
    validates_presence_of :big_log
  end
  if is_small_fire?
    validates_presence_of :small_log
  end
end
```

It seems to just ignore the if conditions and validate everything inside the state D:

The only *sort of* solution I came up with was

```
validates_presence_of :big_log, :if  => Proc.new { |fire| fire.is_big_fire? }
```

But this gets nuts if there are more validations.

```
validates_presence_of :big_log, :if  => Proc.new { |fire| fire.is_big_fire? }
validates :fire_epicness_rating, :inclusion => { :in => %w(epic whowa RUNFORTHEHILLS) }, :if  => Proc.new { |fire| fire.is_big_fire? }
etc
```

Is there some nice way of neatly wrapping these in if blocks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grouping validations thanks to `with_options`is really neat. See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#grouping-conditional-validations).

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using the with_options for group validation.

```
  with_options :if => :driver? do |driver|
    driver.validates_presence_of :truck_serial
    driver.validates_length_of :truck_serial, :maximum => 30
  end

  def driver?
    roles.any? { |role| role.name == "driver" }
  end
```

Source: http://rubyquicktips.com/post/411400798/conditional-validation-using-with-options-to-improve